# Diagnostics from kubernetes is not sending logs to storage account

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics

I need to archive my kube audit logs in a storage accounts and retain it for 100 days. I followed these steps but I dont see the logs in my storage account. I see a folder $logs being created but there is nothing in it? What wrong am I doing? When I query in Logs and run `Azure Diagnostics |where category == "kube-audit"` for timespan of less than 30 min I can see the data there but not in logs

1. Created a storage account in portal.
2. went to kubernetes service of my cluster--> selected diagnostic settings
3. Clicked on new diagnostic setting. selected Kube-audit from list of logs and gave a retention period of 100 days. and selected the same storage account I created in first step from the dropdown.
4. clicked on Save.